# How do I write operator<< for std::variant?

Tags: c++

I’d like to write `operator<<` for `std::variant`. The assumption will be that the `operator<<` for a particular variant will only be valid if `operator<<` is valid for all the types that the variant can contain.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
//g++ (GCC) 7.2.0
//g++ -std=c++1z -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <complex>

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::variant<T, Ts...>& v)
{
    std::visit([&os](auto&& arg) {
        os << arg;
    }, v);
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::complex_literals;
    std::variant<int, std::string, double, std::complex<double>> v = 4;
    std::cout << v << '\n';
    v = "hello";
    std::cout << v << '\n';
    v = 3.14;
    std::cout << v << '\n';
    v = 2. + 3i;
    std::cout << v << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd7f0288d8bca877)

This relies on passing a generic lambda to `std::visit`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52845621/225186) for a problem with the previous version of this answer. This answer has been updated to avoid that problem.

Comment: Can't you just use `template <typename... Ts> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::variant<Ts...>& v)`?

Comment: @Caleth, actually no. He can't, because of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52845621/225186 . The sfinae version was correct.

Comment: @alfC just adding a typename in front of the pack will suffice `template<typename T, typename... Ts>`

Comment: So, the possible fixes are: (1) Restore the SFINAE. (2) Change `variant<Ts...>` to `variant<T, Ts...>`. (3) Add `typename`. (4) Call it a compiler bug and change nothing. I'm tempted to go with 3, but I'm kind of feeling like it should first be added as an answer to [the new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52845621/225186) and discussed with the other solutions there.

Comment: @RobertFisher, what is (3)? (4) It is not a compiler bug.

Comment: @alfC Hmm...regarding (3), maybe I was confused about Caleth's comment about "adding a typename...will suffice". (I wish comments could be threaded, even if we don't want it to become chat.) Regarding (4), I now see that Barry described it as a “language bug” instead of a compiler bug. I misread that. So, I guess (2) is the best choice?

Comment: @Caleth, Yes, that would also work, it is what I proposed in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52846061/225186

Comment: @RobertFisher It would be helpful to make the code you supplied work, it is different to the code in the "Demo" link and doesn't compile.