# Can't stream std::endl with overloaded operator<<() for std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46893057/8414561) describes how to stream a standalone `std::variant`. However, it doesn't seem to work when `std::variant` is stored in a `std::unordered_map`.

The following [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3aecf530b63daecc):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <complex>
#include <unordered_map>

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/46893057/8414561
template<typename... Ts>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::variant<Ts...>& v)
{
    std::visit([&os](auto&& arg) {
        os << arg;
    }, v);
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::complex_literals;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::variant<int, std::string, double, std::complex<double>>> map{
        {0, 4},
        {1, "hello"},
        {2, 3.14},
        {3, 2. + 3i}
    };

    for (const auto& [key, value] : map)
        std::cout << key << "=" << value << std::endl;
}
```

fails to compile with:

```
In file included from main.cpp:3:
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/variant: In instantiation of 'constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<>::_S_default_ctor':
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/variant:1038:11:   required from 'class std::variant<>'
main.cpp:27:50:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/variant:300:4: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Nth_type<0>'
    is_default_constructible_v<typename _Nth_type<0, _Types...>::type>;
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/variant:58:12: note: declaration of 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Nth_type<0>'
     struct _Nth_type;
            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/variant: In instantiation of 'class std::variant<>':
main.cpp:27:50:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/variant:1051:39: error: static assertion failed: variant must have at least one alternative
       static_assert(sizeof...(_Types) > 0,
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

Why does it happen? How is it possible to fix it?

Comment: For whatever reason your overload of `<<` is a better match for `std::cout << std::endl` than the standard `std::osteam& std::operator<<(std::ostream&, std::ostream&(*pf)(std::ostream&))`.

Comment: You might simplify the sample: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5409eb3df588e395

Comment: @Loreto that `__cdecl` isn't going to help the OP's compiler (GCC) decide anything.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In [[temp.arg.explicit]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#arg.explicit-3.sentence-2), we have this amazing sentence:

> A trailing template parameter pack not otherwise deduced will be deduced to an empty sequence of template arguments.

What does this mean? What is a trailing template parameter pack? What does not otherwise deduced mean? These are all good questions that don't really have answers. But this has very interesting consequences. Consider:

```
template <typename... Ts> void f(std::tuple<Ts...>);
f({}); // ok??
```

This is... well-formed. We can't deduce `Ts...` so we deduce it as empty. That leaves us with `std::tuple<>`, which is a perfectly valid type - and a perfectly valid type that can even be instantiated with `{}`. So this compiles!

So what happens when the thing we deduce from the empty parameter pack we conjured up *isn't* a valid type? Here's [an example](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/PtJbyeG6W9g/OVKKykzQBgAJ):

```
template <class... Ts>
struct Y
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Ts)>0, "!");
};


template <class... Ts>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Y<Ts...> const& )
{
    return os << std::endl;
}
```

The `operator<<` is a potential candidate, but deduction fails... or so it would seem. Until we conjure up `Ts...` as empty. But `Y<>` is an invalid type! We don't even try to find out that we can't construct a `Y<>` from `std::endl` - we have *already failed*.

This is fundamentally the same situation you have with `variant`, because `variant<>` is not a valid type.

The easy fix is to simply change your function template from taking a `variant<Ts...>` to a `variant<T, Ts...>`. This can no longer deduce to `variant<>`, which isn't even a possible thing, so we don't have a problem.

Comment: Or `,std::enable_if_t< 0<sizeof...(Ts), bool> = true>` SFINAE.  Because typing `T0, Ts...` is annoying.  ;)

Comment: Excellent catch. Even seems like a useful feature (except when it catches you off guard). Can't `variant<>` by implemented in a SFINAE friendly way?

Comment: @alfC I honestly view it as more of a language bug than a library bug

Comment: @alfC [It can't](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/variant.variant#3)

Comment: I feel like this answer raised more questions then it answers, if you attempt this with other types it does not fail in this way. Why it is attempting this deduction for `std::endl` but not other cases? or if it is attempting the deduction in other cases then why is it valid for other cases? I have to wonder if this is really the intended behavior, it feesl like a very surprising trap.

Comment: @Shafik Because `endl` is a function template. So, like the `{}` example, it's not a thing with a type. So deduction fails and we fall back to empty `Ts...` I very much agree it is a surprising trap.

Comment: @Barry I am sure it is a compiler bug, see my answer. I don't know if the standard could be clearer about that.

Comment: Gotta love C++.

Comment: @Oliv I really don't think so - and either way, it pretty obviously could be clearer.

Comment: @Barry So it is unclear! I still think what I wrote too.

Comment: @Barry, looking closely I think this is a bug of the language, the compiler and the library implementation all at the same time, take a look at https://godbolt.org/z/VGih_4

Comment: BTW, adding a specialization like this is what would make `variant` SFINAE friendly: `namespace std{
    template<> struct variant<>{};
}`.

Comment: I think at least the question "What does not otherwise deduced mean?" has a very clear answer: the template parameter pack is not deduced by any of the rules in [temp.deduct].

Answer (score 7):

For some reason, your code (which looks correct to me) is trying to instantiate `std::variant<>` (empty alternatives) both in clang and gcc.

The workaround I found is to make a template for a specifically non-empty variant.
Since `std::variant` cannot be empty anyway, I think it is usually good to write generic functions for non-empty variants.

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::variant<T, Ts...>& v)
{
    std::visit([&os](auto&& arg) {
        os << arg;
    }, v);
    return os;
}
```

With this change, your code works for me.

---

I also figured out that if `std::variant` had a specialization of `std::variant<>` *without* a single-argument constructor, this problem would not have happened in the first place. See the first lines in https://godbolt.org/z/VGih_4 and how it makes it work.

```
namespace std{
   template<> struct variant<>{ ... no single-argument constructor, optionally add static assert code ... };
}
```

I am doing this just to illustrate the point, I don't necessarely recommend doing this.

Comment: isn't specialising `std::variant` _in `namespace std`_ UB?

Comment: @DevNull, yes and I don't recommend doing it, it is just to show that variant could be implemented in a slightly different way to avoid this pitfall. Meaning that something can be done at the implementation level.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the `std::endl` but I am puzzled why your overload is a better match than the one from [std::basic_ostream::operator<<](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), see [godbolt live example](https://godbolt.org/z/Hk2nfE):

```
<source>:29:12: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::variant<>' requested here
        << std::endl;
           ^
```

and removing the `std::endl` indeed fixes the problem, see it [live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0osU5KeOhexEIRka).

As alfC points out altering your operator to disallow an empty variant does indeed fix the issue, [see it live](https://godbolt.org/z/9fhLnC):

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::variant<T, Ts...>& v)
```

Comment: In my experiment, the code fails whether you have the `std::endl` or not. (and whether you have the `"="`). `gcc 8.1`/`clang 6.0`.

Comment: @alfC the wandbox example I link to shows it working w/o the endl.

Comment: Ah, yes you are right. (I have a `std::cout << std::endl` somewhere else in the test code). It looks as if `std::variant<>` has an implicit contructor from anything?, maybe it is a bug in the implementation of `std::variant`?